# How to expand Maven properties in all files within src/main/webapp?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, war, context.xml, maven-resources-plugin

I'd like to include some Maven properties(*) in `src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml`.

(*) *E.g. `${data-source-name}`, `${data-source-factory}`, `${jdbc-connection-url}` etc. - but in the words of the late, great Leslie Nielsen, that's not important right now.*

Thought this might be achievable using something like the following [maven-resource-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) config:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
      </includes>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

But this results in two versions of context.xml in the WAR file:

```
\META-INF\context.xml                 <=== Properties *not* expanded
\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\context.xml <=== Properties expanded
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit more googling I found out how to do it using the maven-war-plugin instead of the maven-resources-plugin:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <webResources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
          </resource>
        </webResources>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```